# UI Issue with Deploying Laravel in Railway

Tags: laravel, railway

I host my laravel app with railway. It can now be accessed but the issue is that the UI is not showing properly like the css,bootstrap, javascript. Basically the whole design.

I already added this in the .env file:

```
NIXPACKS_BUILD_CMD=npm install && npm run build
```

but it seems not to be working. Can't think of any issues.

Comment: I'm not expert in laravel nor railway, but I think it will be useful to provide more details. Like where you added that line of code, and what do you expect from your UI to show properly.